# How to add a in-app browser in React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, inappbrowser

How to open a web browser in expo rather than using the expo browser.I want open the browser in inside the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following library [react-native-inappbrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser)

follow the installation from the github page

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
import InAppBrowser from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'

...
  async openLink() {
    try {
      const url = 'https://www.google.com'
      if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {
        const result = await InAppBrowser.open(url, {
          // iOS Properties
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: '#453AA4',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          readerMode: false,
          animated: true,
          modalPresentationStyle: 'overFullScreen',
          modalTransitionStyle: 'partialCurl',
          modalEnabled: true,
          // Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
          toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
          secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: false,
          // Specify full animation resource identifier(package:anim/name)
          // or only resource name(in case of animation bundled with app).
          animations: {
            startEnter: 'slide_in_right',
            startExit: 'slide_out_left',
            endEnter: 'slide_in_left',
            endExit: 'slide_out_right'
          },
          headers: {
            'my-custom-header': 'my custom header value'
          },
          waitForRedirectDelay: 0
        })
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(result))
      }
      else Linking.openURL(url)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
    }
  }
...
```

you can check [the example app here](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/tree/master/example)

for expo it becomes little bit complicated please check the related [tutorial by Medium](https://medium.com/lazy-engineering/creating-an-embedded-browser-with-react-native-aea42b54740)

if you want reading mode in ios please refer this link

[reader-mode-webview-component-for-react-native](https://reactnativeexample.com/cross-platform-safari-like-reader-mode-webview-component-for-react-native/)

Comment: is there any expo example.that would be great.

Comment: @ambady Answer Updated

Comment: @ambady i don't now about expo but the reading mode is available in the library i have mentioned in my answer. https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser#ios-options

Comment: i tried the example but it dosent work.shows null is not an object.

Comment: is there any expo snack available for react-native-inappbrowser-reborn? Browsed internet but couldn't find one.

Comment: This library does not work with expo for newer versions of React Native, as per https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/434

Answer (score 1):

The `expo-web-browser` package opens an in app browser.

This worked for me with expo. I tried `react-native-inappbrowser-reborn` first, but isAvailable() was throwing an error.

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser'

...
WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url, {showTitle: true})
```

Comment: Excellent solution - here's a reference: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/