# Is there a React Native InAppBrowser that works with expo?

Tags: react-native, inappbrowser

I am trying to use a in app browser in react native using expo and came across the [react-native-inappbrowser-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn) package and I tried to use the given code example but always get this error when I alert it:

My code:

```
async function handleLink(link) {
 try {
  const url = link;
  if (await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()) {

  } else Linking.openURL(url); 
} catch (error) {
  alert(error.message)
}
```

}

[image]

I was wondering if any of you know this error or if there is a working alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution which i found few weeks ago
here: [How To Add A In-App Browser In React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179745/how-to-add-a-in-app-browser-in-react-native-expo#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=import%20%7B%20Linking%20%7D%20from%20%27react,%7B%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20InAppBrowser.)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution from expo works well for me:

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

const openLink = WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://google.com')

// JSX...
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#webbrowseropenbrowserasyncurl-browserparams) for expo-web-browser

Comment: Initially I was not sure `WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync` was for an in-app browser as the name sounds very general, but it is, and solved the same issue for me.